# Drawing polyline similar to drawing of polyline in DrawingManager

Tags: google-maps-api-3, polyline

This is how I draw my polyline where I click the first point and the polyline is drawn after I click the second point on the map canvas:

[Sample google.maps.Polyline](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-complex)

This how polyline is drawn with the DrawingManager:

[Sample Drawing Manager](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/drawing-tools)

I'd like to draw my regular polyline the same way that is drawn by DrawingManager where the line is continued to show where I move my mouse across the map canvas.

Thanks,

Comment: What does your code look like so far?

Comment: Why can't you use the DrawingManager if that does what you want?  You can remove the controls.

Comment: I can't use the DrawingManager because my custom polyline has markers and labels that are bound to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me, one important detail was specifying `clickable: false` when constructing the polyline, otherwise it didn't register the click event on the map.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Complex Polylines</title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
var poly;
var map;
var existingPolylinePath;
var tempPoly;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 7,
    center: {lat: 41.879, lng: -87.624}  // Center the map on Chicago, USA.
  });

  poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
    strokeColor: '#000000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 3,
    map: map,
    clickable: false
  });

  tempPoly = new google.maps.Polyline({
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 3,
    map: map,
    clickable: false
  });

  // Add a listener for the click event
  map.addListener('click', addLatLng);

  map.addListener('mousemove', function(event) {
    existingPolylinePath = poly.getPath();

    if (existingPolylinePath.length > 0) {
        tempPoly.setPath([existingPolylinePath.getAt(existingPolylinePath.length - 1), event.latLng]);
    }
  });
}

// Handles click events on a map, and adds a new point to the Polyline.
function addLatLng(event) {
  var path = poly.getPath();

  // Because path is an MVCArray, we can simply append a new coordinate
  // and it will automatically appear.
  path.push(event.latLng);

  // Add a new marker at the new plotted point on the polyline.
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: event.latLng,
    title: '#' + path.getLength(),
    map: map
  });
}
    </script>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Excellent.  It was working nicely with map mousemove event in my custom polyline.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this my using the map mouseover event.  This returns a LatLng, say pointA.  If you can write code that will record the previous point that you've drawn, say pointB, then you can render a temporary line from pointA to pointB of a different style in this event.

Let me know if you'd like a code sample.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I will try it with map mousemove event.  If I can't make it to work, I will let you know.